# Detecting when a SerialPort gets disconnected

Tags: .net, winforms

I have an open `SerialPort` and receive data through the `DataReceived` event.

Is there any way to detect if the `SerialPort` gets disconnected?

I tried the `ErrorReceived` and `PinChanged` events but no luck.

In addition to that, `SerialPort.IsOpen` returns true when physically disconnected.

Comment: Is this a USB-Serial adapter?

Comment: @Matt yes, it is a USB-Serial adapter. Thanks.

Comment: It isn't worth the hassle, most USB drivers deal with this **very** poorly.  They just make the entire device disappear, even though you have a handle opened on it.  This tends to end up poorly, an uncatchable exception in a worker thread is common.  Or the worst kind, the driver doesn't even let you close the port, requiring a reboot.  Same wisdom as jerking a flash drive out while Windows is writing to it: don't do it.  Use "Safely remove hardware", the dialog should prompt the user to close your program.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

USB-serial ports are a **huge** pain. See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230311/problem-with-serialport). I'm not sure whether it really was fixed with .NET 4.0, but back in the day I tried to deal with the problem of disconnections crashing the whole program with something like this:

```
public class SafeSerialPort : SerialPort
{
    private Stream theBaseStream;

    public SafeSerialPort(string portName, int baudRate, Parity parity, int dataBits, StopBits stopBits)
        : base(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits)
    {

    }

    public new void Open()
    {
        try
        {
            base.Open();
            theBaseStream = BaseStream;
            GC.SuppressFinalize(BaseStream);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (base.Container != null))
        {
            base.Container.Dispose();               
        }
        try
        {
            if (theBaseStream.CanRead)
            {
                theBaseStream.Close();
                GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(theBaseStream);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignore exception - bug with USB - serial adapters.
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Apologies to whoever I adapted this from, it seems I failed to make a note of it in my code. The problem apparently stemmed from how .NET handled the underlying stream in the case of the serial port disappearing. It seemed you couldn't close the stream after the serial port is disconnected.

Another strategy I used was to create a small program that did just the serial communication part and exposed a WCF service for my main program to connect to. That way, when the USB-serial adapter flakes out and crashes the communication program, I can just automatically restart it from my main program.

Finally, I don't know why nobody ever marketed a locking USB port to avoid the whole accidental disconnection problem, especially with USB-serial adapters!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `IsOpen` value is only set  back to `false` when the `Close` method is executed.

You could try caputuring the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message and using that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Wouldn't that just tell you if someone uninstalled the serial port itself?

Comment: @JonB in case of a Usb adapter my guess is that is what happens if you unplug the Usb device!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the problem of an unhandleable exception (and not being able to detect/circumvent the problem in code) as soon as the USB-Serial adapter had been disconnected. I can confirm that the solution from Mattt Burland works.

Simplified version:

```
class SafeSerialPort : SerialPort {
    public new void Open() {
        if (!base.IsOpen) {
            base.Open();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this.BaseStream);
        }
    }

    public new void Close() {
        if (base.IsOpen) {
            GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(this.BaseStream);
            base.Close();   
        }           
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        try {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me - this dispose method throws an exception "unhandled dispose..."

Comment: Whats the exact exception/inner exception thrown? The line `base.Dispose(disposing);` is expected to throw an exception because of the SerialToUSB adapter, but it should be handled by the try/catch.

Comment: the exception says "Safe handle has been closed". this probably happens because SerialStream.EventLoopRunner.WaitForCommResult(..) is running an internal loop which is trying to access the handle. How did you fix this issue?

Comment: Its a Microsoft known issue. Here's a workaround for this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/8a1825d2-c84b-4620-91e7-3934a4d47330

Answer (score 2):

Update for those who are still facing this problem; a few points...

1. Telling users "don't disconnect the USB device" is futile and just annoys everyone involved. Even though we wish they wouldn't, we know they will yank the device out whilst our program is running...
2. Earlier versions of the framework **did** update the `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` immediately on yank, but 4.7 does not update the list for an open port. We have a background thread that checks this list for changes (as suggested above), which used to work great, but it no longer works...
3. Because of this framework change (bug?), we updated the check thread to test `SerialPort.IsOpen()`, which in 4.7 immediately reports the device closed when the user yanks out the device. We do see the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message immediately on yank but for our app its easier to just test `SerialPort.IsOpen()` in the background thread.

Comment: Checking SerialPort.IsOpen() in the background works nicely. Easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If the device you're connecting to uses the CD pin, you can watch for that to change (other pins may apply for some devices using flow control). If not, then there isn't really a definitive way to do this.

Depending on the expected behavior of the connected device, you might want to implement a timeout or some kind of keep alive.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with a simple backgroundworker.
I continuously check/set all current ports into an array and if new ports are different to my ports-array I get the changed ports from these 2 arrays.

Example:

```
// global variable
List<string> oldPorts = new List<string>();    // contains all connected serial ports

private void bgw_checkSerialPorts_DoWork(object seder, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string[] currentPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();    // get all connected serial ports
        string[] diffPorts = currentPorts.Except(oldPorts.ToArray());    // get the differences between currentPorts[] and oldPorts-list

        if (diffPorts.Length > 0)
        {
            // iterate all changed ports
            for (int i = 0; i < diff.Length; i++)
            {
                // check if changed port was in old list
                if (oldPorts.Contains(diff[i]))
                {
                    // port in diff[] was removed
                }
                else
                {
                    // port in diff[] is a new device
                }
            }
        }

        oldPorts = currentPorts.ToList();   // update oldPortlist

        // check every 100ms
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: except, if I have the serial port open, it wont disappear from the GetPortNames list when removed. This does work fine if the ports are not yet open.

Comment: This code does NOT solve the problem! the code is nonsense

Answer (score 0):

Use the C# SerialPort.CDHolding flag.

So save the bool to a lastCDHolding flag,  before your open and read loop.

After you read test SerialPort.CDHolding != lastCDHolding to trap changes or just test SerialPort.CDHoldin==false to detect the port was closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a RFID device.
It's possible to detect a USB removal by sending dummy data.

Normally I only have to receive data from the RFID, but it doesn't hurt (in my case) to send some data each second.
When the USB cable is disconnected the serialPort.Write throws an exception.
Then the port has to be closed immediately, else the program hangs.

```
bool verify_connection()
{
    try
    {
        if (serialport.isOpen)
        {
            serialport.WriteLine("Dummy");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        serialport.Close();
    }
    return serialport.isOpen;
}
```

Tested with .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. After several tries, I got what I wanted by using `SerialPort.DsrHolding`.

It retuns false as soon as the usb cable is yanked out. I don't know of other conditions where this may fail. But this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this solution with a edited of code from Jeb.
I always have a background timer for such cases (but you can also start it when you connect the Comport) When I connect the Comport I set the bool "canDisconnect" to true and this is how I made the work always perfect.

```
    bool canDisconnect = false;


    private void tmrBackgroundTick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (canDisconnect == true ){ 
        //Automatic disconnect program if Comport is removed 
            try
            {
                 ComPort.WriteLine("test");
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                disconnect();
                canDisconnect = false;
            }
        
        }
    }
```