# Top level exception not catching anything

Tags: c#, exception

My entry point should catch any exception not being handled at a lower level:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace EyeScanner
{
    static class Program
    {
        [FlagsAttribute]
        public enum EXECUTION_STATE : uint
        {
            ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040,
            ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
            ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002,
            ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
            // Legacy flag, should not be used.
            // ES_USER_PRESENT = 0x00000004
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern EXECUTION_STATE SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE esFlags);
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);

            bool isNew;
            Mutex m = new Mutex(false, "EyeScannerByOphthaMetrics", out isNew);
            try
            {
                if (isNew) Application.Run(new CheckSystemForm());
                else { MessageBox.Show("An other instance of EyeScanner is running"); }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would expect that last `catch()` to catch any exception which is not dealt with, but I have a situation (100% reproducable) to create a `NullReferenceException` (turn the hardware attached to the system off), but I can't breakpoint it since it happens at a random point, I can't catch it, and I cannot get a Call Stack (when I try to debug it, and Visual Studio says an exception occurred, there is no CallStack, and no dissassembly available). I activated the `NullReferenceException` in the debug menu, but that did not catch it.

How can I deal with this? I get an exception with 100%, but I can't debug it to find out why it would happen.

Edit: 
The EventLog:

```
Anwendung: EyeScanner.exe
Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319
Beschreibung: Der Prozess wurde aufgrund einer unbehandelten Ausnahme beendet.
Ausnahmeinformationen: System.ObjectDisposedException
Stapel:
   bei System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean ByRef)
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Boolean ByRef)
   bei Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetOverlappedResult(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*, Int32 ByRef, Boolean)
   bei System.IO.Ports.SerialStream+EventLoopRunner.WaitForCommEvent()
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I have absolutely no idea where to look for this error...

Edit2:

I used that SafeSerialStream now, and the error occurs in there:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (base.Container != null))
            {
                base.Container.Dispose();
            }
            try
            {
                if (theBaseStream.CanRead)
                {
                    theBaseStream.Close();
                    GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(theBaseStream);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignore exception - bug with USB - serial adapters.
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

The code crashes exactly after trying to execute `theBaseStream.Close();`, even though its in a `try{] catch{}` block. What can I do about that?

Edit 3:

Console output on crash:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
'EyeScanner.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Transactions.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.resources.dll'
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unbehandelte Ausnahme</Description><AppDomain>EyeScanner.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.</Message><StackTrace>   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CheckCollectedDelegateMDA(IntPtr pEntryThunk)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

Comment: Different thread, perhaps? Seems like the most obvious cause.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be running something through a USB-Serial adapter by any chance?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Can we even catch exceptions thrown from unmanaged code? That was entirely new to me!

Comment: @MattBurland: Yes, I have a USB Serial Microcontroller attached. I have it in suspicion of causing this, since this only happens after having triggered an image, but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: The Application object has a couple of handlers for Thread exceptions:  see OnThreadException and ThreadException.

Comment: You can use [other ways to catch "unhandled" exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762526/how-can-i-make-something-that-catches-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-a-winforms-a).

Comment: @AntonRoth: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408476/detecting-when-a-serialport-gets-disconnected/13419871#13419871) answer will help. USB-Serial ports are a pain and there was (still is?) a bug that caused an uncatchable exception.

Comment: Check if the exception appear in EventLog. If not, maybe there is a suppressed exception somewhere.

Comment: Attach the debugger, and set to to break even on handled NullReferenceException, look at the callstack, put handler at the bottom.

Comment: @MattBurland: Okay, it really is caused by the USB Serial Controller, but what can I do about it? I implemented your code, but it still breaks

Comment: @AntonRoth: Hmmm...not sure. You did use the open method that suppressing finalization of the stream right (the one in my code)? Ultimately, I ended up isolating all the serial port stuff in it's own process and used WCF to communicate with my main application. That way I can just kill and restart the process if it acts up. You could also try a few different USB/Serial adapters. They all suck (and all get their chips from the same place), but some suck marginally less.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Releasing a unplugged virtual Serial Port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835881/releasing-a-unplugged-virtual-serial-port)

Comment: @MattBurland: Can you post your WCF application idea as an answer? I have done that now, and the application is now working as intended, so your suggestion perfectly suited my needs.

Comment: @HansPassant: in the beginning I had no idea where to even look for the error. Yes, it was caused by a USB SerialPort, but I only figured that out after the hints given here, so I had no idea that it was a replicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately the solution I've used for dealing with USB/Serial port issues (which are a constant headache) is to separate the part of my code that deals with the serial port into a completely separate process that exposes a service using WCF. The WCF service can expose methods that map directly (or almost directly - it's a good chance to add some abstraction for lower level stuff) to the functions of the serial port interface and if the process flakes out, you can just restart it from your main application without the main application going.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an unhandled exception on a thread is killing your process. This behaviour is described in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms228965%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

As a test, invoke the legacy exception handling policy via the app config file as described in the article. In the `<runtime>` section, add the following setting:

```
<legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
```

Then see if your `catch` picks up the exception, or at least if the exception stack trace is written to the console.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nope, that did not help. It seems to be some stupid issue with the USB - serial micro controller. I am thinking about putting it into another thread or so, but the issue is that even though I know what seems to be happening I cannot avoid it.

Comment: And nothing on the debug output console either? :-(

Comment: Yes, I put that on Edit 3, no idea what its supposed to tell me there. Its no call stack though

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you are not catching exception, because you are not getting it inside try-catch?
Just in case, to be sure... Can you put line 
`Mutex m = new Mutex(false, "EyeScannerByOphthaMetrics", out isNew);` 
inside your try block?

Comment: No, it was indeed caused by my USB-Serial Controller. I know got it working.