# SerialPort.Read not throwing TimeoutException

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have the following code

```
    private SerialPort _port = null;

    public SerialReader(string portname, int baudrate, Parity parity, int databits, StopBits stopbits, int readTimeoutMs = 10000)
    {
        //Set serial-port
        _port = new SerialPort();
        _port.PortName = portname;
        _port.BaudRate = baudrate;
        _port.Parity = parity;
        _port.DataBits = databits;
        _port.StopBits = stopbits;
        _port.ReadTimeout = readTimeoutMs;
        _port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort_DataReceivedNew);
        _port.Open();
    }

    private void SerialPort_DataReceivedNew(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
        _buffer = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
        try
        {
            port.Read(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);
        }
        catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
        {
            bool doDispose = true;
            if (ReadTimeout != null)
                ReadTimeout(ex, out doDispose);

            if(doDispose)
                this.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        ///////////
    }
```

If the connected devices sends data all work fine, but if I unplug it, the program waits for other data forever without throwing `System.TimeoutException` ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143549%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says that it should throw exception).

I verified this by placing a breakpoint on `bool doDispose = true;` and it is never reached.

The assembly is compiled as "Debug".

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Edit

It is possible that SerialPort_DataReceivedNew isn't called because no data is actually received, if this is the case, how can I catch errors?

Edit 2

To make it work I edited the code like this:

Added methods BeginGetData and PollSerialPort

```
    public void BeginGetData()
    {
        _port.Open();
        Thread pollingThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(PollSerialPort));
        pollingThread.Start();
    }

    private void PollSerialPort()
    {
        while (this.SerialPort_DataReceivedNew()) ;
    }
```

And edited SerialPort_DataReceivedNew

```
    private bool SerialPort_DataReceivedNew()
    {
        _buffer = new byte[_port.BytesToRead];
        try
        {
            if (_port.Read(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length) == 0)
                _port.Write("\0");
        }
        catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
        {
            bool doDispose = true;
            if (ReadTimeout != null)
                ReadTimeout (this, out doDispose);

            if (doDispose)
            {
                _port.Close();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        ///////////
    }
```

On `_port.Write("\0");` I have the `TimeoutException`

Comment: maybe Read returns some value? 0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408476/detecting-when-a-serialport-gets-disconnected

Answer (score 0):

Put your breakpoint earlier to see if `DataReceived` is ever called. Even if it is, and there is no data (weird) your buffer size is zero because `BytesToRead` is zero so it will never timeout. Try polling the serial port in a timer event instead.