# Listener for SerialPort disconnection

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm using a default  `SerialPort` to connect a single USB device to my application. My UI needs to toggle between its `Disconnected` and `Connected` states, depending on the connection with the device.

The connection part is simple and handled just fine.

The disconnection however could be caused by `port.Close()` *(currently handled)* but also unplugging or powering off the device.

I tried looking for answers in the following but all I was able to find were clear explanations of the problem (possibly outdated aswell?):

- [Detecting when a SerialPort gets disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408476/detecting-when-a-serialport-gets-disconnected)
- [Problem with SerialPort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230311/problem-with-serialport)

How can I add some kind of listener to the `SerialPort`'s connection state?

---

*Nb: I'm a beginner with .NET, so any extra info is appreciated*

Comment: There are no happy answers because it is hard problem to solve.  SerialPort still exists in spite of 50 years of major hardware changes because it is easy to use.  Plug & play is not easy at all, the .NET Framework having no support for it whatsoever is one major hangup.  Even the OS can't fix the problem, that is why it has the "Safely Remove Hardware" tray icon.  Which is what you need to use to safely unplug the USB device.

Comment: @HansPassant - I don't really understand. Let alone the risk of causing trouble by unplugging while writing, SerialPort seems able to know if a device is plugged. Is there really no kind of callback when it goes from plugged to unplugged?

Comment: I generally use the `isOpen` method to determine if the port connection is still open.  Unfortunately, it doesn't tell you if the other device closed, because the port can be held open still.  But if you do a `Close()` then this method will return false if the port isnt open.  I have mine in a one second timer `if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)`

Comment: @Baddack - That sounds unreliable. Maybe I'm better off telling people rough unplugging will crash the program, rather than fiddling around with this.